# Drupal 7 - Show Text on Image Hover

Tags: drupal

Hi friends i have used views here.I have 3 images whenever i hover on an image some text has to be shown on that image plus the image must look blur.
Any modules available or any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Do you know how to create a view template?  You can add the jquery code to the view template.

Comment: @lam4fun can you please tell me how to create view template?